# Azure devops: how to build two queued commits together

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

For example, if there is a commit A, it queues a build. In that time, there are other commits B and C, it will queue another 2 builds. want to build both commits B and C together. it is possible or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The Batching changes in Trigger Setting would achieve your goal. If you set **batch** to true, when a pipeline is running (Commit A), the system waits until the run is completed, then starts another run with all changes that have not yet been built (Both Commits B and C).

For Classic Pipeline, enable the below setting.

[image]

For YAML pipeline, write batch in the trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#batching-ci-runs

```
# specific branch build with batching
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```